# Laravel Eloquent ORM Soft delete and restore many items for me at the same time

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i think there is a bug in softdelete and restore with Eloquent ORM in Laravel .
i have a table like these 
[My Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94WeB.png)

UPDATED : i made a video now for the problem : [VIDEO OF MY PROBLEM](https://youtu.be/Agmc5kdBM44)

and my code to softdelete is

```
 try {
       $p= Post::findOrFail($id);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
return "error";
    }
    $p->delete();
    return "Post deleted";
```

and my code for restore is :

```
`try {
        $p= Post::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return "error";
    }
    $p->restore();
    return "Post restored";`
```

..
the problem is sometimes :
 when i delete post number 3 , it delete number 3 and number 2 at the same time and sometimes work fine , n with restore same thing too sometimes i restore for example number 3 n it restore number 1 also at the same time.
 i didnt understand why , i tried different code like 'where' statement n 'find' n 'destroy'.
like :

```
Post::withTrashed()->where('id', $id)->restore();
Post::find($id)->delete();
```

but same problem sometimes delete n restore work normally sometimes go crazy n delete or restore many items at the same time . 
i tried also different version of laravel 5.2 n 5.4 .
i use mysql 5.6.35 , mamp server php 7.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this code helpful for you.

```
$products = Product::onlyTrashed()
            ->whereIn('id', $request->product_ids)
            ->restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it by calling on Model instance:

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->delete();
```

Since you already know your model Id, you might do this:

```
Post::destroy($id)
```

Or delete it by Query:

```
$deletedPost = Post::where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Btw, i dont think you need those try/catch there. Try without it. Also, if you have problems, try to do dd($id) and see what it dumps. If its ok, move on and do dd($p) and see if you are getting the proper model.

Take a good look at your variables, dump them or if you can use debugger, go line by line to see where it goes wrong.
Hope this helped a bit :)
Good luck with problem!

Comment: thank you , but i already did that at first , those try n catch is my last try to be sure that one item is selected , idont know whats the problem , and i dont know if someone have it too , if you are free try to do the same n delete n restore many times not only one item , thank you

Comment: Simo i dont understand now- what do you mean by try to delete n restore many times? You mean many models(posts)? Or do you mean many times like delete a post, and delete another post, then another etc... Or to delete a few posts at the same time?

Comment: imean "delete a post, and delete another post, then another etc" . i tried now i deleted post number 3 then i deleted number 2 then i deleted number 1 but when i try to restore number 3 , number 2 is restored also automaticly  so its like this .

Comment: Do this, and not findOrFial()
Post::withTrashed()
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->restore();
And then tell me if you get only that id restored.

Comment: thank you but i already did it , that was the first thing , if u have time u can see it in my laptop its crazy xd

Comment: And this one: 
Post::where('id', $id) ->restore(); 
withTrashed is returning Posts with all softDeletes. I think that just Post::where...$id->restore() will do the job you need

Comment: sure, add me on skype i ll try to help - vladimir_nikolic

Answer (score 0):

You don't need try catch block to soft delete. Eloquent provides delete() and restore().
Add `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes`  trait
and `protected $dates = ['deleted_at']` to your model
add a deleted_at column to your database table(use helper/manually migrate).
Now you can call delete() and restore() method onto your model.
This will set current datetime value to the deleted_at column (initially they are null).

Hope this will help.

laravel-5.4 doc: [soft-delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Comment: i already did that , that try catch was only my last try .n i did a teamviwer session with @Vladd n he see the problem , its amazing softdelete n restore go crazy n it delete ore restore sometimes work normally n sometimes go crazy n restore or delete  two items or more even if just one item it selected n we checked also by dd($id) n we see that just one item was selected

Comment: what about route model binding  
  
    ```public function destroy( \App\Post $id)
    {
        $id->delete();
    }```  
@Simo

Comment: same thing : public function destroy(Post $id)
    {
         $id->delete();
    } it work at first n deleted items normally but when i restored number 1 n number 3 then when i tried to delte number with same method that i type in this comment it delete me number 1 n number 3 at the same time